# How to display ES, LS, EF, LF in numbers using MS Project, Network Diagram?

Tags: ms-project, tools

For Network Diagram, MS Project has the following fields in date format:

1. Early Start `ES`.
2. Early Finish `EF`.
3. Late Start `LS`.
4. Late Finish `LF`

Although, How can I display them in Network Diagram in numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from the Gantt Chart view you need to add 4 custom columns for (ES, EF, LS, LF).

Through clicking on `Add New Column` from the table in right pane and choose columns of type numbers.

1. Right Click column's header and choose `Custom Fields`.
2. Click on formula button from Custom Attributes.
3. insert into formula popup the right equation, as follows:

   1. Early Start (ES): `ProjDateDiff([Project Start],[Early Start])/[Minutes Per Day]`
   2. Early Finish (EF): `ProjDateDiff([Project Start],[Early Finish])/[Minutes Per Day]`
   3. Late Start (LS): `ProjDateDiff([Project Start],[Late Start])/[Minutes Per Day]`
   4. Late Finish (LF): `(ProjDateDiff([Late Finish],[Project Start])/[Minutes Per Day])*-1`
4. Then Click View > Network Diagram.
5. After that, From `FORMAT` Tab click `Boxes Styles` > More Templates > Create new Template.
6. Choose the columns you created earlier in template's cells accordingly.